# C# HttpClient throttling requests to SendGrid

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient, sendgrid

I have built a C# Console Application for sending batch emails through SendGrid which is hosted as a Web Job in Azure. I'm batching the requests at 100 at a time as async tasks.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", requestObj).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When running the application the batches start sending quickly at roughly 1 batch (100 emails) per second. After about 20 batches this reduces to 20 seconds per batch.

In Azure we are using the S1 Standard Service Plan, which should be fine for this kind of operation. Should I be using a higher service plan or is there something in my code that could be throttling these requests? SendGrid docs say they can handle up to 3000 requests per second so I have ruled out problems at their end.

Comment: My gut feeling is that an S1 Standard instance shouldn't even be breaking a sweat with that workload. Have you checked the metrics on the S1 instance's overview tab in the portal? You can also see raw numbers in the Kudu console.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have increased the service plan to test and am getting the same result. The metrics show it's not really being touched. It's being throttled elsewhere.

Comment: I checked the App Service limits. There's not a throttle on the number of outbound connections. How about looking at the max number of connections allowed to a network host? See docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc(v=vs.110).aspx. This would make sense since you're basically initiating outbound connections async and as fast as you can go.

Comment: You might be right. I have not set this setting and according to the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y(v=vs.110).aspx) the max outgoing connections is 2. I will increase this limit and try again.

Comment: I notice this question has been put "on hold" by somebody who works for Microsoft Azure. Seems to me they would be the perfect person to try to help the OP answer a question about Azure as I'm guessing that's what they're being paid to do. Instead of making any effort to help him they voted to close it when it seems like a perfectly reasonable question. //rollseyes.